# Jsoup get href within a class

Tags: java, class, href, jsoup

I have this html code that I need to parse
    `<a class="sushi-restaurant" href="/greatSushi">Best Sushi in town</a>`

I know there's an example for jsoup that you can get all links in a page,e.g.

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
for (Element link : links) {
print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"),
trim(link.text(), 35));
}
```

but I need a piece of code that can return me the href for that specific class.

Thanks guys

Comment: <a class="sushi-place" href="/someurl">Best Sushi</a> sorry this code converted to best sushi. sorry

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can select elements by class. This example finds elements with the class `sushi-restaurant`, then gets the absolute URL of the first result.

Make sure that when you parse the HTML, you specify the base URL (where the document was fetched from) to allow jsoup to determine what the absolute URL of a link is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = "<a class=\"sushi-restaurant\" href=\"/greatSushi\">Best Sushi in town</a>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html, "http://example.com/");
    // find all <a class="sushi-restaurant">...
    Elements links = doc.select("a.sushi-restaurant");
    Element link = links.first();
    // 'abs:' makes "/greatsushi" = "http://example.com/greatsushi":
    String url = link.attr("abs:href");
    System.out.println("url = " + url);
}
```

Shorter version:

```
String url = doc.select("a.sushi-restaurant").first().attr("abs:href");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: your answer makes total sense, but I get null value when I run Elements links = doc.select("a.sushi-restaurant"); , and I know sushi-restaurant class exists cuz when I run getElementByClass("sushi-restaurant") and it works.

Comment: select() will never return a null -- it may return 0 elements, but never null. I have updated to include a full snippet which I've tested prints the URL correctly. Can you test that and let me know? Using jsoup 1.6.1.

Comment: You were right. I had the wrong class name. Awesome.Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the class name had a space in it how would you handle it ? eg: "sushi restaurant". Would "a.sushi restaurant" work?

Answer (score 0):

```
Elements links = doc.select("a");
for (Element link : links) {
String attribute=link.attr("class");
if(attribute.equalsIgnoreCase("sushi-place")){
print   link.href//You probably need this
   }
}
```